# Debian Network 2 subnets one interface proxmox

Tags: debian, networking, bridge

I have a box that runs proxmox with a debian 7 base. It is virtualizing openvz venet VMs. The host node and all VMs are currently inside of the same /24 . I recently got a new subnet and wanted to be able to assign IPs in that subnet to the VMs as well, however the network is not usable in the VMs with the new subnet assigned.

My interfaces file currently looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.xxx.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.1
        bridge_ports eth2
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
iface vmbr0 inet6 static
        address xxxx:xxx:x:4::2
        netmask 64
        gateway xxxx:xxx:x:4::1
```

I have attempted creating a route for all of the new /24 subnet to route through the vmbr0 interface but I haven't had any luck.

Perhaps I am just missing something simple, would appreciate any help.